# Is there a way to add a signature field to a form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to do a credit card authorization form and would like the customer to be able to electronically sign the form for legal purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) [Terms of Service](https://www.cognitoforms.com/terms):

> You are expressly prohibited from collecting and storing credit card
>   information in Cognito Forms, except as supported by Cognito Forms for
>   processing online payments using secure third-party payment processors
>   such as Stripe.  When used properly, Cognito Forms servers never
>   process, store or transmit credit card information.

This is under the section on Data Collection.  PCI credit card processing guidelines discourage the collection and storage of credit card information.  We are actively working on adding support for [Subscription Billing](https://trello.com/c/1XpfGKm8), which will support automatic recurring payments through Cognito Forms, which provides a more secure alternative to capturing actual credit card information.

We also plan to add support for [Digital Signatures](https://trello.com/c/iDqwRjjR), including a great experience on mobile devices.  This is near the top of our Next Up list.